# RxJava + GRPC recover from errors and retry requests

Tags: android, rx-java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to recover from errors using RxJava and GRPC. This is my observable:

```
Observable<Object> observable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        try {
            Grpc.MyRequest request = Grpc.MyRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setToken(mToken)
                    .build();
            Grpc.MyResponse reply = mStub.mytest(request);
            return reply;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ///
        }
    }).cache();
```

And this is the subscription:

```
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
            })
            .subscribe((result) -> {
                MyResponse res = ((MyResponse) result);
                if (res.getCode()!=0) {
                    //Check error code and try to refresh token and repeat this request after.
                } 
            },throwable -> {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            });
```

So, when I get the error from my GRPC service, depending on the error code, I want to try and recover from it by doing another request, and then repeating the original request. I'm not sure how to use RxJava ***retrywhen***.
What is the most elegant way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Error recovery in an observer chain does require a bit of tap dancing, and is by no means elegant. However, it can be contained in the observer chain.

```
boolean isRecoverable( Throwable t ) {
  // this test can be as sophisticated as you want
  if ( t instanceof StatusRuntimeException ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

...
.retryWhen( throwableObservable -> 
  throwableObservable.flatMap( t -> isRecoverable( t ) 
           ? Observable.just("") 
           : Observable.error( t ) )
...
```

This approach allows you to decide what you want to do with the error. You could add a delay the `just()` so that you don't retry immediately. Instead of the `just()`, you could return an `Observable` that fetches a new API token.